# Jquery variable says TypeError: test is undefined

Tags: jquery

I have `var test = $(this).attr('id');`. I have declared test as var but I do not understand
why I am getting

> TypeError: test is undefined.

Why is this error appearing?

Comment: You need to include more code.

Comment: You will only receive `test is undefined` if you try to use `test` in some context or another. Please share the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable, `test`, is `undefined` because whatever `this` is (perhaps your `window`) doesn't have an `id` attribute. As such, when you request the value of the non-existent attribute, `undefined` is returned, and assigned as the value of `test`. It's very likely that you're confusing the contextual meaning of `this`.

Below I'm calling `this` from the global scope, as well as in a callback function. Notice the difference in their references. Depending on where `this` is called, and *how* any surrounding functions are called, `this` can mean very different things.

```
var outerTest = $(this).width(); // this is the window

$("img").on("click", function () {
    var innerTest = $(this).attr("id"); // this is the image
});
```

See: [`this` on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)